# Serverless.yml config to deploy one lambda function to a service without removing the others

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have the following serverless.yml:

```
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7

package:
  individually: true

functions:
  main:
    handler: src/main.lambda_handler
    name: my-new-func
    package:
      individually: true
```

But deploying this will purge all other functions in `my-service` apparently, even though I use the `individually: true` option.

Is it possible to deploy one lambda function without change to the other functions?

Comment: Also `serverless deploy function -f main` does not work for new functions

Comment: From the discussion [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4269) what I want to do is not possible because serverless use CloudFormation which always redeploy everything

Comment: Maybe you can try importing existing resources to CF first.